# options.editorconfig from prettier-cli

Tags: prettier, editorconfig

Is there a way to pass that `options.editorconfig` true flag using the cli without a configuration file. I can't get prettier to respect the `.editorconfig` file.

I don't way this isn't the default. An .editorconfig is a configuration file, way do I need another configuration just to honor the original configuration.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#editorconfig

I have a directory with one `.js` file and an `.editorconfig`.

```
testdir:
    file01.js
    .editorconfig
```

```
root = true
indent_style = tab

[*.{js,ts,css}]
indent_size = 4

[*.{html,json}]
indent_size = 2
```

running prettier from `testdir` using the cli with:

`npx prettier -w .`

formats the `file01.js` to use spaces as indentation. Since prettier is invoked from that directory it should see that `.editorconfig` file, it is not posting to a specific file path that could be any where.

I also naively tried to pass --editorconfig:
`npx prettier --editorconfig -w .`